# Write to port 0cf8h fails with segfault

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, pci

I have an AMD processor of e2-2000 model. THis is family 0fh.
According to family 0fh BKDG I have this code to read device and vendor ID:

```
ReadPCIConfiguration:
movq    $0x80000100, %rax
movq    $0x0cf8, %rdx
outl    %eax, %dx          # sigsegv caught here
movq    $0x0cfc, %rdx
inl     %dx, %eax
ret
```

As far as I know the algorithm to read/write PCI configuration is as follows:

- write target bus number, device number function number and offset or register number to configuration address port
- perform 1-, 2- or 4-byte r/w operation from/to configuration data port

Ports 0xcf8..0xcfb - configuration address port (doubleword)

Bits meaning:

- 31 -                EnReg - enable the transaction  (R/W)
- 24..31 -            reserved                        (R/O)
- 16..23 -            BusNum                          (R/W)
- 11..15 -            DevNum                          (R/W)
- 8..10 -             FuncNum                         (R/W)
- 2..7 -              RegNum                          (R/W)
- 0..1 -              Reserved                        (R/O)

So, I write to bus - 0, dev - 0, func - 1, reg - 00

Am I doing something wrong?

(I run the compiled and linked application from userspace, GNU/Debian "Wheezy" Linux 3.11.6)

Comment: I'm, not a hardware guy but probably the OS doesn't allow you to write directly to the ports? There is most definitely a syscall for that, to ensure only processes with the right privileges do so.

Comment: Maybe you are right. But the thing is that, in future, the code should run at the start of the OS (to reconfigure system memory map) and I'd like to test the code at least for read access and read correctness.

Comment: Virtualize it? Run it before the OS inside virtualbox. That will sure as hell give no segfault since there's no OS, but I have no clue as to what your code does!

Comment: Ive got the point.
I found a solution is a call named `ioperm` and `iopl`.
Maybe I should delete the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux does not, by default, allow userland code to write to I/O ports.  (Doing so can be quite dangerous from a security perspective.)  If you’d like Linux to give your process access to the I/O ports, you have two options:

1. You can use the `ioperm` system call.  However, `ioperm` has been deprecated for some time, and Josh Triplett recently [pushed a patch](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.virtualization/21009) that allows users to remove it from the kernel.  Avoid `ioperm` if you want your code to continue working for the forseeable future.
2. You can read from and write to /dev/port.  See [mem(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/mem.4.html).  Your process will, obviously, need read and write permissions for /dev/mem; on Wheezy, that means it needs to run as root, unless you change the permissions on the device.

Comment: So, you say `ioperm` is now deprecated. What about `iopl` syscall?

Comment: Have a look at Josh Triplett’s e-mail.  The patch he pushed allows users to compile out both `iopl` and `ioperm`.

Comment: Uh-huh.
Looks, like I shall use the `iopl` for my own tests and use `/dev/port` in the future.

But why should they disable the `ioperm` & `iopl`? Maybe thats for some security reasons? 

Anyway, thanks for your quick answer.